# can't highlight <p> text in html

Tags: html, css, visibility, highlight

I'm currently working on a package for Macaulay2 that allows the visualization and editing of graphs. This happens in a browser, and the program generates a Macaulay2 constructor for the graph as you make edits, however there has been a persistent problem, we are unable to select the text that gets generated.

I am somewhat new to html/css and I'm pretty sure the problem is not in our javascript. When we checked out old git commits, it appeared the problem began after I added the popupMenu and tried toggling visibility changing the css attribute display to "none"/"inline" to "hidden"/"visible", however i tried both switching back and removing the popupMenu completely and I was still unable to highlight text. I also tried adding the following lines of code to my css to change z-index and ability to highlight text, to no avail.

```
  #constructorString {
    -o-user-select: text;
    -moz-user-select: text;
    -webkit-user-select: text;
    user-select: text;
    z-index: 100;
  }
  #incString {
    -o-user-select: text;
    -moz-user-select: text;
    -webkit-user-select: text;
    user-select: text;
    z-index: 100;
  }
  #adjString {
    -o-user-select: text;
    -moz-user-select: text;
    -webkit-user-select: text;
    user-select: text;
    z-index: 100;
  }
```

the complete source is at http://www.elliotkorte.com/visGraph-template.html

i suspect i need some kind of padding around either the popupMenu, the canvasElement3d, or the paragraph tags, however adding "padding-bottom: 30px;" to the css for all questionable elements did not work.

thank you for the help!

Comment: Is it possible that some javascript is preventing the selection? Maybe this: `window.addEventListener("mousedown", function(e) {e.preventDefault();`

Comment: There is no CSS present that should be preventing selection. Like showdev suggested, make sure your click/mousedown events are being bound to your svg id "canvasElement2d" instead of the body or window.

Comment: Thank you guys for the help, after all that all i had to do was remove one line of code, `e.preventDefault();` in my mousedown listeners. I had it in because it was in all the mouse listener examples for three.js and d3.js but i didn't realize before that those listeners didn't apply to the whole document, only the canvas they're contained in.